# Qbservable implementation

Tags: c#, system.reactive, streaminsight

Does anyone know of a good implementation of this?

I want to do CEP, but using StreamInsight is somewhat expensive to put it mildly. The licensing cost alone is rather burdensome. Is there a reactive framework implementing Qbservable alternative that can plug into any ODBC database or even write to disk?

Comment: it appears that StreamInsight is included in the SQL Server 2012 license.

Comment: @M. Babcock, I think "Qbservable" is correct:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.qbservable(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: The number of questions about Qbservable that get 'corrected' to Observable is getting silly now

Comment: @KirkWoll - My mistake, thanks for correcting it. (the _Thanks_ doesn't belong though)

Comment: @RichK What's silly is getting cute with language in the LINQ API. QueryableObservable would be entirely more appropriate. :P

Comment: what a silly name:). I don't think you'll find it, that's pretty 'cutting edge' in that area. Hope someone refutes me though, though doubt it.

Comment: @Boo yes it's included, but you can't scale it cheaply. Streaminsight is coupled to the same server the SQL Server is at. It's not like a traditional app where you can share conn string. Sql Server is ~7k a pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StreamInsight is NOT coupled to the same server that SQL Server is on. You can have StreamInsight installed independently of SQL Server. It does require a SQL Server license however.

Comment: You're right. It uses the sql server compact edition, which can be embedded in the application. It seems like the application initializer allows you to pass in a remote sql server also if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The [Reactive Extensions project contains a Reactive Parsers implementation](http://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parsers&referringTitle=Documentation). This allows for query syntax over an IObservable stream of events that can be used to implement Complex Event Processing. Depending on the problem domain, this may be even more appropriate than Qbservable.

The problem will be the plugging events from a database or file - but that is not particularly difficult with streams and IObservables.

Is there any reason you need Qbservable specifically? What is the problem being solved?

Comment: Scalability. I need to crunch large amount of events. In order of about 1TB. And it has to be reliable as much as possible. A standard Rx running on standard machine will puke. I'm guessing I would need more than the parser implementation I need a QueryProvider of sort that can write the events to and from disk.